# Updating a field from an inner join - or default value on a miss

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to figure out if this can be done in one step instead of two. Right now, I update every target field with a default value, then update again based on an inner join.

```
create table #tmp (buyer varchar(1000), contract_assignee varchar(1000), contract_assignee_address varchar(1000), lenderid int)

insert into #tmp (buyer, lenderid)
select 'Luke Skywalker', 100
union
select 'Leia Organa', 400
union
select 'Han Solo', 500
union
select 'Chewbacca', 300
union
select 'Govenor Tarkin', 200
union
select 'Darth Vader', 200

create table #assignees (contract_assignee varchar(1000), contract_assignee_address varchar(1000), lenderid int)
insert into #assignees 
select 'Toshi Credit Union', '142 Sandstone Dr, Tattooine', 0
union
select 'First National Bank of Coruscant', '253 Exegol Parkway', 200 
union
select 'Jawa Predatory Loans', 'Somewhere in the Desert', 300

update #tmp 
set contract_assignee = a.contract_assignee
, contract_assignee_address = a.contract_assignee_address
from (select * from #assignees where lenderid = 0) a -- the default value

update t 
set contract_assignee = a.contract_assignee
, contract_assignee_address = a.contract_assignee_address
from #tmp t
inner join #assignees a 
on t.lenderid = a.lenderid 

select * from #tmp

drop table #assignees 
drop table #tmp
```

Comment: FYI, there's no need for those old `UNION` statements anymore for `INSERT`s; SQL Server has supported `VALUES` table constructs since *at least* SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

One method would to always `JOIN` to the "default" row, and then `LEFT JOIN` to the actual row. Then you can use `ISNULL` to return the "default" value when the actual row wasn't found:

```sql
UPDATE T 
SET contract_assignee = ISNULL(a.contract_assignee,d.contract_assignee),
    contract_assignee_address = ISNULL(a.contract_assignee_address,d.contract_assignee_address)
FROM #TMP T
     JOIN #assignees d ON d.lenderid = 0
     LEFT JOIN #assignees a ON t.lenderid = a.lenderid;
```